# Python's random module made inaccessible

Tags: python

When I call random.sample(arr,length) an error returns random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given).I've tried importing numpy under a different name, which doesn't fix the problem.Any thoughts? Thanks

```
import numpy.random
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import *


points = [[1,1],[1.5,2],[3,4],[5,7],[3.5,5],[4.5,5], [3.5,4]]


def cluster(X,center):
  clusters = {}

  for x in X:

    z= min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-center[i[0]]))  for i in enumerate(center)], key=lambda t:t[1])

    try:
      clusters[z].append(x)
    except KeyError:
      clusters[z]=[x]

  return clusters

def update(oldcenter,clusters):

 d=[]
 r=[]
 newcenter=[]

 for k in clusters:
  if k[0]==0: 
   d.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])

  else:
   r.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])

 c=np.mean(d, axis=0)
 u=np.mean(r,axis=0)
 newcenter.append(c)
 newcenter.append(u)


 return newcenter

def shouldStop(oldcenter,center, iterations):
    MAX_ITERATIONS=0
    if iterations > MAX_ITERATIONS: return True
    u=np.array_equal(center,oldcenter)
    return u

def init_board(N):
    X = np.array([(random.uniform(1,4), random.uniform(1, 4)) for i in range(4)])
    return X

def kmeans(X,k):    

  clusters={}
  iterations = 0
  oldcenter=([[],[]])
  center = random.sample(X,k)                       

  while not shouldStop(oldcenter, center, iterations):
        # Save old centroids for convergence test. Book keeping.
        oldcenter=center

        iterations += 1
        clusters=cluster(X,center)  
        center=update(oldcenter,clusters)

  return (center,clusters)

X=init_board(4)
(center,clusters)=kmeans(X,2)
print "center:",center
#print "clusters:", clusters
```

Comment: Please post the actual, complete error message.

Comment: Look at the last `import`

Comment: Don't `import *`. This is why.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked, I am a beginner in python. So, could you explain to me when I should use import *?

Comment: The only purpose of `import *` is to make future references to objects in the module shorter. But it affects readability, as you experienced it

Answer (score 4):

When you use `from numpy import *` you import all items that are in the `numpy` namespace into your scripts namespace. When you do this any functions/variables/etc that have the same name will be overwritten by the items from the `numpy` namespace.

`numpy` has a subpackage called `numpy.random` which then overwrote your `random` import as the code below shows:

```
import random

# Here random is the Python stdlib random package.

from numpy import *

# As numpy has a random package, numpy.random, 
# random is now the numpy.random package as it has been overwritten.
```

In this case you should instead use `import numpy as np` which will allow you to access both:

```
import random

# random now contains the stdlib random package

import numpy as np

# np.random now contains the numpy.random package
```

Answer (score -2):

Your points is `List` type, so you should convert it to an array

```
points = np.asarray(point)
```

Also, you should use `import random`

Comment: Your answer is very very difficult to read, I highly recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, using that link as a reference can greatly help the visibility and clarity of your answer.